# Is there node api hook in drupal 7

Tags: 7, hooks, nodes

Is there still a `hook_nodeapi` in drupal 7 or do i have to try `hook_node_load` hook for appending some content to node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hook_nodeapi()` is split into multiple hooks in Drupal 7, so you should use [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7)